# How to feed a Variable to a placeholder by feed_dict in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

One way to solve my problem is first getting the value of my variable (GPU copy to CPU), and then feed the value using feed_dict (CPU copy to GPU). But this involves copying the data from GPU to CPU and then copy back, which is slower than just computing in CPU. I hope to do it without data copying.

Another way to solve my problem is that directly build a graph on the variables I am using. But I have hundreds of variables, I need to build the graph for each variable. All the graphs are executing the same computation, just on different variables. This is even slower because I need to build hundreds of graphs.

Is there a way to solve this problem gracefully in Tensorflow? In Theano, this problem is naturally solved because Theano accepts both CPU tensors and GPU tensors as function arguments.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep all the data on GPU, you could transfer all your CPU data once to variables pinned on GPU (using `sess.run(tf.assign..., feed_dict)`, and then from them on only use GPU variables, like is done in this example -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_preloaded_var.py

Comment: I have several hundred samples. I first generate a feature matrix for each sample in the training set. Then I use nearest neighbor classifier. For each testing sample, I want to find the nearest training sample. I store each feature matrix in a variable. Only using GPU variables seems to be the slowest way. I guess that is because I need to create a small computation graph to compute the distance of two feature matrixes (variables) each time.

Comment: (It might be useful to post your code here) One way could be to have one big variable which stores all the feature matrices and then match your test sample against this feature matrix(something like softmax with the number of classes being the same as the number of training points).